# Python: Json with arrays

Tags: python, arrays, json, put

I am trying to construct the following JSON in python to send in a curl PUT request.

```
{"entries":[
    {"op": "create", "ip": "x.x.x.x","subnet": "y"},
    {"op": "update", "id": "<acl_entry_id>", "ip": "y.y.y.y", "subnet": "p"},
    {"op": "delete", "id": "<acl_entry_id>"}
]}
```

I tried the below logic :

```
 payload = {"op": "create", "ip": ip,"subnet": subnet}
 data = json.dumps(payload)
```

This is not giving me an array. The current data frame looks like this :

```
{"subnet": "24", "ip": "x.x.x.x", "op": "create"}
```

I am new to python, Any recommendations here to fix the dataset?

Comment: Dicts are encoded as objects. *Lists* are encoded as arrays.

Comment: Also, don't shell out to `curl` to make a request; use something like the `requests` library, which among other things will handle JSON encoding and decoding for you.

Comment: The Python code to create it should be identical to the JSON. Just put the appropriate variables in all the places.

Answer (score 0):

The Python syntax for this happens to be identical to the JSON syntax. Just put the variables where you need them.

```
payload = {"entries":[
    {"op": "create", "ip": ip,"subnet": subnet},
    {"op": "update", "id": acl_entry_id, "ip": ip, "subnet": subnet},
    {"op": "delete", "id": acl_entry_id}
]}
```